# How to ignore unset member variables in Response.ok(object).build()'s result

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

- I am using Jersey for RestAPI development. In my scenario, there is a case where the value of a particular member variable is not set. But, when we return Response.ok(Object).build(), this particular member variable is set to the default value and is send in the Response json.
- But, I need to avoid this particular entry in the returned Response json if it is not set. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you checkout JsonInclude annotation

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html

You may try Include.NON_DEFAULT. You can set this at the bean level or globally

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: It's not affecting the Response object. After applying the @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.NOT_DEFAULT), still I get the same output(i.e., printing the unset member variable data with default value set to it)

Comment: did you try updating the global ObjectMapper? You may want to add some sample bean to your question so that other can help you.

Comment: I had the followwng format of code `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class ProcessMgmtParams {
    
    private int machineId;}`